# Is it safe to make a gapi.auth without popup combined with a server roundtrip?

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I know that if you are already logged into a Google account in a browser (e.g. on Gmail) and you call:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, callbackAuthResult);
```

with **immediate: true** option, it won't show you the popup and you will be "silently" authenticated.

In the case, when you are not logged into the Google account, the call will respond with **error: "immediate_failed"** and then you have to use a call with **immediate: false** option, which will show you the popup.
([example](https://google-api-javascript-client.googlecode.com/hg/samples/authSample.html))

But I didn't want to show it, because some users can have the popups blocked in their browsers.

So I decided to solve this problem with the server roundtrip. I mean, if the call with the **immediate: true** option fail, I simply redirect the user to (in my case) *Java servlet* on URL:

```
/authorization
```

There, the servlet generate standard Google auth URL

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String url = new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl(
                Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.CLIENT_CALLBACK,
                Arrays.asList(Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE)
                ).build();
              response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
```

Like in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl) or [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2). The servlet redirects me in *Google auth page* page where I have to log in to some Google Account and I have to agree with some of the app's permissions. Exactly the same as with the popup, except this happened in the classic browser window.

If you set in [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com) / APIs & auth / Credentials / Web application / Authorized redirect URIs: *https://your-project.appspot.com/oauthcallback.html*, then you will be redirected from the *Google auth page* to this *oauthcallback.html*.

There in the **oauthcallback.html** an **access_token** is extracted from the URL and verified through:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' + params['access_token'], true);
```

If OK, I save temporarily this **access_token** to *localStorage* and finally redirect the user to my application https://your-project.appspot.com.

On the beginning (after the gapi is loaded), there is my authentication procedure where at first I manually insert the received **access_token** to the gapi:

```
gapi.auth.setToken({access_token: localStorage.getItem('token')});
```

and then the *gapi.auth.authorize* call with the **immediate: true** option is called **without the popup and successfully**.

So, my question is: **is this safe? Or needlessly overwhelmed?**

Comment: no reason to go to the server. if you want to avoid the popup, simply dont use auth with popup mode and instead use auth with redirect and do everything from the client js. no need to have  actual server code.

Comment: So my auth procedure is OK, but instead of server call I can use redirect to:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
 scope=email%20profile&
 state=%2Fprofile&
 redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Foauthcallback&
 response_type=token&
 client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com
?
Is there some security pitfall I should know about?